# Mostrar el resultado de un sp SQL Server 2008 en un label web form C# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, sql

Buen día a todos.
Tengo un sp SQL Server 2008 que me arroja de resultado lo siguiente:

```
Total_Registros
       1
```

Por otro lado, tengo un formulario que contiene un label (lbl_totales),

```
nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Label ID="lbl_totales" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

el cual lo me gustaría que mostrara el resultado de este sp. El sp tal cual, me arroja el resultado antes indicado. Tengo este código el cual  lo estoy probando, sin embargo, me sigue sin mostrar el resultado en mi label. ¿alguien sabe donde se encuentra mi error? ó ¿Me podrían brindar alguna idea adicional?.

```
  protected void TotalReg()
    {

        clsConexioncs cnx = new clsConexioncs();
        try
        {
            DataSet ds;
            cnx.Conexion = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultPRM"].ToString();
            cnx.PreparaComandoSP("prm_spTotalRegistrosNAV");
            ds= cnx.EjecutaComandoDataSet();


            foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows )
            {
                //lbl_totales.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                lbl_totales.Text = dr["Total_Registros"].ToString();
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox("Ha ocurrido el siguiente error " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        finally { cnx = null; }
    }
```

Resultado esperado sería lo siguiente:

```
Total_registros:  [lbl_totales]
```

Donde lbl_totales seria el label donde mostraría el resultado del sp. Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
Total_registros: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Buebas tardes si lo que quieres es saber el numero registros devueltos en la consulta ya no tienes que hacer el foreach tan solo basta con lo siguiente.

```
lbl_totales.Text = ds.Tables.[0].Rows.Count.toString();
```

Ahora bien si quieres obtener la suma total del campo **Total_Registros** tendrias que hacer lo siguiente

```
int sumaTotal
foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows )
{
    sumaTotal += Convert.toInt32(dr["Total_Registros"]);
}
lbl_totales.Text = sumaTotal.toString();
```

Aunque esto lo podrias hacer en tu procesimiento **prm_spTotalRegistrosNAV**

Saludos.